# How do I automate field declarations within postgres using an array?

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I am trying to create a series of fields ina postgres database that use the same functions in the same orders in a table and would like to know if there is some way to automate this using another function.

The following is an example of my current sql and what I would like to be able to do is pass a function and array of [10,20] and have it output the same fields.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(in1 integer, in2 integer) RETURNS integer AS '
SELECT CASE
    WHEN in1is NULL THEN 0
    WHEN in1 ~ ''^[0-9]+$'' = ''f'' THEN 0
    WHEN in1 = transtech_target THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END' LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2(in1 integer, in2 integer) RETURNS integer AS '
SELECT CASE
    WHEN in1 is NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 0
END' LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT 
   f1(inf1, '10') AS f10,
   f2(inf2, '10') AS f10up,
   f2(inf3, '10') AS f10dn,
   f1(inf1, '20') AS f20,
   f2(inf2, '20') AS f20up,
   f2(inf3, '20') AS f20dn,
FROM table;
```

Any ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you have to know at planning time what your result looks like in terms of columns.  So you can't really further automate as such.  There are however some options you might have depending on your PostgreSQL version.  These include:

1. Dynamic SQL with variable numbers of columns and returning JSON or HSTORE instead of a tuple.
2. Dynamic SQL with variable numbers of columns and returning XML instead of tuple.
3. Dynamic sql with variable numbers of columns and returning a REFCURSOR.  this would preserve tuples but would require transactions and require separate client-side side FETCH commands.
4. Straight SQL and return variable numbers of rows instead of columns.....

However you can't do this in SQL if you want to have variable numbers or names of columns returned.